# python : print one message each time

Tags: python

I have the code below that is supposed to print one message each time :

```
if pitch > 0 and  pitch < 180 :
    print "forward"

if pitch > -180 and pitch < 0 :
    print "backward"

if yaw  < 0 and  yaw > -180 :
    print "left"

if yaw  < 180 and yaw  > 0 :
    print "right"

if (yaw == yawN )and (pitch == pitchN) :
    print "stable"
```

What I get is two messages at a time

```
forward
left
forward
left
forward
left
```

What can I do to make it one message each time?

Comment: What are the values of `pitch` and `yaw`?

Comment: could you please show all of your code?

Comment: this code could print up to 3 messages

Comment: yes but 3 messages check by `pitch` and `yaw` value. Please give those value.

Comment: I don't understand. Exactly what do you want the output to be, and what input are you testing to get this output?

Comment: There is no connection between `yaw` and `pitch`..

Comment: pitch and yaw are two angles : the message depends on the angles values variations to give directions : backward  or forward for pitch / left or right for yaw .So the command line , shows two consecutive line of left/right messages and forward/backward messages

Comment: @MarounMaroun exactly there is no connection between them , and i want to find out how to print one massage each time , i event thought of threads , but it did not give important result

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i want the out put to be like this : right ( if direction right) ; left (if diriction left) , backward (if direction backward) , forward (if direction forward) ; i want to see one message in the screen not two

Answer (score 1):

You'll get one message for `yaw` and one message for `pitch` because you've done nothing to stop that happening, you could make it print one message by simply replacing your `if`s with `elif`s, like so:

```
if pitch > 0 and  pitch < 180 :
    print "forward"

elif pitch > -180 and pitch < 0 :
    print "backward"

elif yaw  < 0 and  yaw > -180 :
    print "left"

elif yaw  < 180 and yaw  > 0 :
    print "right"

else :
    print "stable"
```

However, this is unlikely to do what you want because would you really want a pitch angle of 1 degree combined with a yaw angle of 175 degrees reported as "forward"? Instead you likely want to compare the magnitude of the values (`abs(pitch)` will return the magnitude) and then base your response on the value with the higher magnitude, like so:

```
if pitch == 0 and yaw == 0 :
    # Eliminate the stable option first to cut down on comparisons
    print("stable")

elif abs(pitch) > abs(yaw) :
    # If we're pitching more than yawing, only give the pitch message
    if pitch > 0 :
        print "forward"
    else :
        print "backward"

else :
    # The other options have been eliminated, so we must be yawing more than pitching
    if yaw  < 0 :
        print "left"

    else :
        print "right"
```

(I've assumed you're maintaining your angles in the range `-180 < theta <= 180`; if not you should probably do that)

Although you might also want a set of mixed messages for when there's significant inputs in both directions, so that if yaw is 90 and pitch is 90 it reports something like "forward-right".

Comment: I tried the magnitude method but it did not give precise results

Comment: What did you do? Imprecise how?

Comment: a comparison between abs values and giving higher priority to the highest value

Comment: That didn't answer either my questions. I've added example code for you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use if-elif to get desired output like in the below:

```
if pitch > 0 and  pitch < 180 :
    print "forward"

elif pitch > -180 and pitch < 0 :
    print "backward"

elif yaw  < 0 and  yaw > -180 :
    print "left"

elif yaw  < 180 and yaw  > 0 :
    print "right"

elif (yaw == yawN )and (pitch == pitchN) :
    print "stable"

else:
    print "default"
```

See if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

That's is because it can go forward **and** left (for example). So you will always get two messages.